# autoplay html5 video with external link on mobiles

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video, html5-video

I have created a web page that auto plays a full screen background video.

On top of the video is a div that contains text & a link to an external site - this works fine in all desktop browsers.

How do i recreate the same setup to play on mobile devices - would I need to use javascript in order to achieve this?

I have spent many hours trawling google for a definitive answer and am now very confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the actual problem? is your issue that video won't auto-play? this is by design on most mobile devices and not easy to get around

Comment: @ Offbeatmammal thanks for picking up this thread... I understand that my full screen background video won't play on ios.  Instead I can replace this with an image. I have a link to an external site that overlays the 'video' but this doesn't work on ios either - how can i get the link to work on ios? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay for HTML5 video is not allowed on mobile devices such as iOS or Android. You can read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/using_html5_audio_video/device-specificconsiderations/device-specificconsiderations.html) for the whys and hows on iOS.

On iPhone the video plays in the default (fullscreen) Quicktime player. So there is no real background notion (this could be accomplished in a native app where inline playback of video is allowed but not in the Safari/web browser). You would need to stick to an image I guess.

On the iPad or on Android in order to accomplish what you want you will need to bind your video tag to a touch event/button (like when a user 'touch' to enter your site), and on this event initiate the play sequence for the video (in your case the video being set to occupy the full width and height of the viewport).

Thanks